# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.backend.tensorflow_backend'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run the code

```
import keras
```

And I am getting this stack trace.
I have tried reinstalling keras and tensorflow but nothing in working.
Here is the stack trace.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-88d96843a926> in <module>
----> 1 import keras

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 from . import losses_utils
      8 from . import metrics_utils

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .load_backend import epsilon
      2 from .load_backend import set_epsilon
      3 from .load_backend import floatx
      4 from .load_backend import set_floatx
      5 from .load_backend import cast_to_floatx

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py in <module>
     88 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     89     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 90     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     91 else:
     92     # Try and load external backend.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.backend.tensorflow_backend'
```

Comment: How did you install Keras? It seems that the code itself is broken, that could happen if yo install unofficial versions or from unofficial sources.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have installed keras in jupyter notebook using ```!pip install keras```

Comment: I would completely get rid of anaconda and install keras on your system python. Anaconda probably broke something.

Answer (score 8):

instead of use something like

```
    from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
```

Try to use it like

```
    from keras.backend import set_session
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing tip. It works in my code. I just wonder if it fully backward compatible. Or some functions won't be available?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

and then

```
pip install Keras==2.2.0
```

This worked for me with Python 3.7.

Answer (score 3):

In Tensorflow 2.0.0+ versions you should just put "compat.v1" after tf and dont use "tensorflow_backend" name. Like this:

```
tf.keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.set_session() -> tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session()
```

Comment: Does this really work? I just tried it out but no luck. I just get this message:

TypeError: set_session() missing 1 required positional argument: 'session'

Comment: @kennentropy worked for me. It probably changes with the environment you use and where you get modules. I have win 10 home, installed modules with pip, python 3.8.5. It looks like Tensorflow is not clear about this point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I finally got it working but what I did was downgrading TensorFlow to version 1.13.1, running python 2.7, Keras 2.0.1

Comment: I think I was using python 3.7 at the time.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use anaconda or pip to install tensorflow and keras, and each method met the same problem.

At last I found the problem is because the version of tensorflow or keras. When I install tensorflow==2.2 and keras==2.4.3(latest), no matter which tools I used I will meet this problem.When I install tensorflow==1.14 and keras==2.2, the code works well.

My python version is 3.5.2 under ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Neither worked for me at this point in time until I simply installed Keras from within Anaconda Navigator

Answer (score 2):

Just install tensorflow 2.1.0 or 2.2.0 It already has Keras inside. Dont mix using `pip` and `conda`. Carry on with what you have started.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

or,

```
conda install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to run `pip install` *and* `conda install` one after the other?

Comment: i dont suggest mixing those. If you start with conda, carry on with conda. Or, likewise

Comment: Yes, but in your answer it seems as you suggest running them sequentially; please update to clarify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Keras and reinstall the version 2.2.0 in your system, it will definately work with Tensorflow 2.2. Then you won't have to downgrade you tensorflow ie. less pain of changing codes ;)

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install Keras==2.2.0
```

For my case, I had Python 3.7(latest bug fix)

Answer (score 0):

for tensorflow==2.4.1 this works:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was solved by installing a given specific version of Keras.

```
pip install Keras==2.2.4
```